# Angular 2 component data disappears

Tags: javascript, angular, forms, frontend

using angular im having an object of data which i need to push to it another object
but when it does some of my component data disappear
code : let res = this.dialog.open(SiteMainPopupComponent,{data:{step:'Select_shipping_options'}});
res.afterClosed().subscribe((Finished: boolean) => {

```
      if(Finished){
        this.updatePrice();
        ( < FormArray > this.SiteDataService.myCart.get('CartActualOrder')).push(this.fb.control(this.SiteDataService.IskaToCart.value));
```